# How to perform AWS S3 multi-part upload without sharing secret keys

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

I am developing an image sharing application in which I have to deal with a huge number of S3 image uploads.Currently, I am using S3 pre-signed URLs to upload images from mobile applications.The problem is that this method doesn't support multipart upload.

So I researched on API gateway and lambda file uploads.Finally, I implemented a solution. Here the problem is that API gateway has a content length limit of 10 MB and lambda can only accept JSON payload of max 6 MB.

I am using nodejs as the backend server. How can I perform S3 multipart uploads from the mobile application without sharing IAM secret keys?

I found another way of signing each multipart URL from the server.But there is no proper guide for implementation.

Can somebody give a proper answer?

NB: I don't want to give public write access to S3 bucket and I am not using EC2 servers.

Comment: You should be able to provide multiple pre-signed URLs, each for a part of a multipart upload operation, rather than a single pre-signed URL for a monolithic PutObject..See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=796288.

Answer (score 2):

The proper answer in all likelihood involves using AWS Cognito to issue temporary credentials to each mobile device/user when they are needed, with only the minimum privileges they need - i.e. 'throw away' keys.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this